# If a value is X, how can I check if X is less than 0.05 and write "YES" or "NO" in another cell in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r

I have the following kind of file (variable "a"):

```
P                   OK
0.009109607206037   NA
0.296054274328919   NA
0.359366011629242   NA
4.77143881428015E-05    NA
0.002556197639041   NA
1.68489333654225E-05    NA
0.413536654401798   NA
7.8906355718309E-06 NA
0.183951454595559   NA
0.018652061230313   NA
9.62042790189634E-15    NA
0.151533362472736   NA
0.037140932397797   NA
0.350401082523352   NA
0.673474391454102   NA
0.000329419618776   NA
```

These are data generated in R in a data.frame, what I did was calculate the P-value, but, in the final file, I have more than 5000 lines, so, to make my life easier, I put a marker as the last column, but I can't figure out how to make an if/else condition here.

So, I've tried:

```
If a$P<0.05
 a$OK <- "Significant"
Else
 a$OK <- "Not-Significant
```

But this didn't work... Can someone help me to fix this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ifelse`:

```
a$OK <- ifelse(a$P < 0.05, "Significant", "Non-Signficant")
```

The `ifelse` function is vectorized, meaning that the above will populate the entire `OK` column in your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

[Tim Biegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295556/if-a-value-is-x-how-can-i-check-if-x-is-less-than-0-05-and-write-yes-or-no/54295581#54295581) is the canonical way of solving the problem but `ifelse` is known to be slow.
Here are two alternatives. They create an index and use it to get the values from a vector of strings.
The first uses a logical result and then adds 1 because R is one-based.
The second uses `findInterval`.

```
OK1 <- c("Significant", "Non-Signficant")[(a$P >= 0.05) + 1]
OK2 <- c("Significant", "Non-Signficant")[findInterval(a$P, c(0, 0.05, 1))]
OK3 <- ifelse(a$P < 0.05, "Significant", "Non-Signficant")

identical(OK1, OK2)    # TRUE
identical(OK1, OK3)    # TRUE
```

Now some speed comparisons.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  loginx = c("Significant", "Non-Signficant")[(a$P >= 0.05) + 1],
  findInt = c("Significant", "Non-Signficant")[findInterval(a$P, c(0, 0.05, 1))],
  ifelse = ifelse(a$P < 0.05, "Significant", "Non-Signficant")
)

mb
#Unit: microseconds
#    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#  loginx 14.450 15.8580 17.52272 16.7705 18.6525 63.106   100
# findInt 18.726 21.0170 23.00090 23.2135 24.3680 46.071   100
#  ifelse 31.940 33.0065 33.70410 33.4330 33.9235 48.500   100


autoplot(mb)
```

[image]